# APNS push notifications not being sent

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications, pem

Actually I am new to APNS and I have been using some help from the online forums and blogs. I am using PHP to implement the server side. The following is my PHP code

```
<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = '0f744707bebcf74f9b7c25d48e3358945f6aa01da5ddb387462c7eaf61bbad78';

// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'pushchat';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo '
```

' . PHP_EOL;

```
// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

I have converted the .p12 file to a PEM file and named it as ck.pem and has hosted it on the same location as the php file resides. When I execute the PHP file, the following gets printed. Is there something I am missing. I am doubtful about the certificate part.

```
Connected to APNS
Message successfully delivered
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually replaced the UDID of the device with the Device Token and it works like a charm. You cannot use UDID anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, using the exact same example code - works perfect for android but fails for IOS with no returning error.

To fix my problem I had to create the SSL cert again against the app and then run

```
openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out  aps_development.pem

openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out  aps_developmentKey.pem -in ios_development.p12

cat aps_development.pem aps_developmentKey.pem > ck.pem
```

Finially tested against:
    openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert aps_development.pem -key aps_developmentKey.pem -CAfile entrust_2048_ca.cer

After this everything worked perfect, that was on the 29th Sept - Its now stopped working so I think its the Certs again but at least it may help you with your solution.

Comment: Can you please elucidate? I have worked with SSL many times before. But this is not the usual SSL right? So, Can you guide me through the server side of the following?

Installation of this SSL in server(The path details and all)
And the following two lines?

stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);


In my code, what naming conventions should I follow to name the ck.pem file? Can i rename the PEM file to anything?